# Get collection length from mongodb in reactjs redux

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

[Here's the error that the response looks like an empty array not a number "the length"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcAxd.png)

I want to display collection length from mongodb in react with redux.

Here's my code:

Action:

**carActions.js**

```
export const howMany = () => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({ type: CAR_NUMBER_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/cars')

    dispatch({ type: CAR_NUMBER_SUCCESS, data })
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: CAR_NUMBER_FAIL, payload: error.message})
}
```

}

Reducer:

**carReducer.js**

```
export const carNumberReducer = (state = { cars: [] }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case CAR_NUMBER_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, cars: [] }
    case CAR_NUMBER_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, success: true, cars: action.payload }
    case CAR_NUMBER_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
        return state
}
```

}

Here where it would be displayed:

**carScreen.js**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

const carNumber = useSelector(state => state.carNumber)
const { cars } = carNumber
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(howMany());
}, [dispatch])
return (
        <div>
            {cars.map((cars) => (
                <p key={cars._id}>{cars}</p>
            ))}
        </div>)}
```

Comment: Where is an error?

Comment: I've updated the post with an image if u can see it

Comment: Have U swagger? Can You test that Api returns collection proper?

Comment: I tested it on postman and it correctly works

Comment: Have you configured CORS?

Comment: I don't use it, absolutely the error is from reducer but i don't know why